# Schmitt trigger using NE555P gives wrong output

Tags: schmitt-trigger, 555

I am trying to create a Schmitt trigger using NE555P to generate square pulses from some periodically changing signals. I used the following circuit diagram and applied some sinusoidal waves (3.3v). What I am getting at the output is just the inverted input (not square pulses). What is the problem with my circuit. Any suggestions, please.[image]

Comment: What is your supply voltage? If, for example, it is 12V, then the thresholds of the comparators are 4V and 8V, so your 3.3V input is insufficient to set and reset the circuit.

Comment: I bet you haven't supplied a DC supply to the chip.

Comment: It makes no sense that the output is inverted sine wave, perhaps there is a problem with circuit implementation. Take a picture of the device.

Comment: Do you have the signal source ground connected to the circuit ground and scope ground?

Comment: and: wouldn't it make more sense to build a Schmitt trigger with an opamp? You'd need way less supply voltage with a modern opamp. Or, you just use a  logic gate – 3.3V happens to be TTL logic level compatible, so that there's logic gates with schmitt-trigger inputs that just work out of the box.

Comment: I checked all the comments and tried everything. I have a common ground. I increased the voltage level of the signal (5v), I checked the voltage across pin-2 and GND and also across the pin-6 abd GND. They are exactly half(6v) of Vcc (12v). I am not getting any output. I guess IC is damaged.