# DC Supply voltage drop in a Schmitt trigger circuit

Tags: 555, schmitt-trigger, voltage

[image]

I developed a Schmitt trigger using IC NE555P. I supplied a Vcc of +6v from a DC source. My input is a sinusoidal wave (peak-peak = 4V). First I set the voltage in DC source (+6v) and when I connect it to the schmitt trigger circuit,  voltage is dropping to less than 1 V. Then I had to increase the **CURRENT** in the DC source to increase the voltage to +6V. But it is overheating the IC.  I have to use the same +6V supply in a circuit (an amplifier circuit) along with this Schmitt trigger. Why this voltage drop.  Is increasing the current is safe for NE555P.

Comment: Why on earth would someone implement a schmitt trigger with an NE555?! that sounds like the least sensible thing to do.

Comment: what is the most sensible thing to do? :P.  any suggestions, please. Unfortunately, I work with a circuit from 2000. :(

Comment: that's only 20 years ago. The NE555 is about 50 years old, and believe me, it's been obsolete longer than it hasn't been since. Anyway, previous Schmitt trigger question of yours, I [already](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/506015/schmitt-trigger-using-ne555p-gives-wrong-output#comment1293804_506015) recommended something.

Comment: Showing ALL the pins on the diagram is very wise. || 
[555 functional description here](https://www.ques10.com/p/22770/explain-the-functional-block-diagram-of-timer-ic-1/) 

Your circuit is NOT a Schmitt trigger BUT the output should switch when Vin rises above 2/3 x Vcc and again when it falls below 1/3 Vcc. As Vin is capacitor coupled it should work for an input sinewave of amplitude of about Vcc/3 or greater. So your 4Vpp gives 1v to 5v at pins 2 & 6 so should work OK . Check that the pins not shown are either open or terminated properly.